# AUTOINCREMENT does not work on OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access

I'm doing MS Access database file using OleDb. Here is the snippet:

```
OleDbCommand command = oleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText =
    "CREATE TABLE MyTable (" +
    "[Count] LONG NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "[TimeAndDateTested] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, " +
    "[SerialNumber] VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL, " +
    "[TestResult] BIT NOT NULL)";                    

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Do you know what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change:

```
"[Count] LONG NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
```

with:

```
"[Count] IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
```

and it worked.

Comment: Interesting . . . Are you using ac 2007 or 2010? I have not upgraded yet. However, in ac 2003, the COUNTER keyword worked for me, and IDENTITY failed. Interesting, and apologies for sterring you wrong!

Comment: No, thats all right. Thanks anyway. Im using Access 2007 but I saved it as an Access 2003 file. I'll check it on 2003. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

In Access 2003, this statement will create the table structure I think you want.  Notice I changed the name of the first field to Kount because Count is a reserved word in Access.  You could enclose the name in square brackets to avoid ambiguity, but I prefer to just avoid using reserved words as object names.  TIMESTAMP is recognized as a synonym for DATETIME.  VARCHAR is recognized as a synonym for TEXT.  BIT will get you a field type which Access calls Yes/No.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (
Kount COUNTER CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY,
TimeAndDateTested TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
SerialNumber VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
TestResult BIT NOT NULL);
```

I assigned a primary key constraint to Kount, and named the constraint as "pkey".  Not Null and unique are implied by the primary key constraint, so you needn't specify them separately.

Comment: I didn't know that the TIMESTAMP would resolve to DateTime. On the rest, nicely done.

Comment: I think it's very odd that Jet/ACE DDL would make TIMESTAMP a synomym of DATETIME, since they aren't by any stretch of the imagination the same thing. I guess the point is that it degrades the meaning to the part of the definition of TIMESTAMP that's supported by Jet/ACE, but it's the most trivial part of the meaning, so hardly useful, seems to me.

Answer (score 2):

When using DDL against MS Access, you want to use COUNTER to specify an auto-incrementing integer Field.

Comment: Not certain, but you you may run into trouble with TIMESTAMP as well. Instead Define the TimeAndDateTested field as DateTime, and Set the Default value to NOW()

Comment: @XIVSOlutions: that's isn't a timestamp field, as it won't update each time the record is changed. However, in A2010, it's possible to implement a table-level data macro to do so (works like a trigger), but it's not possible at the engine-level in any provious version of Jet/ACE (it has to be done at the application level).

Comment: @XIVSolutions How do you exactly do that? I changed the AUTOINCREMENT keyword to COUNTER and "...syntax error" is still flagging.

Comment: A. What version of Access are you using?

Comment: @David Fenton - Yeah, it is probably time to check into ac 2010, but I just don't use it so much anymore after I got hold of SQL Server. THanks though. They gave us Table-level macros, huh? Now if they would update the JET/OLE library so that it would work in a 64 bit environment, we'd be getting somewhere!

Comment: Uh, 64-bit ACE has been available since before A2010 was released. I don't know about OLEDB, but certainly Jet/ACE is 64-bit now. However, you have to remember that the version of Jet (4.0) that ships with the OS is never going to be anything other than 32-bit.

Comment: I may have to look onto it again - In vs2008, I ran into a problem with the Compile Settings - Turned out that it needed to be set to compile specifically for 32 Bit machines (as opposed to "any machine"). The research I did at the time led me to understand they weren't going to be supporting 64 bit in JET. It must be what you describe about the version that ships with the OS.

Comment: AH. It was the JET OLEDB Driver. Not the JET ACE. Good thing I wasvague in the previous comment. Sure, I uh, meant the JET OLE driver . .  .  ;-)

Comment: AND, the items I looked at to figure out what was causing my problem (supposedly) pre-dated the news of the 64 bit ACE driver for Office 2010. God, you just can't blink for a minute without putting your foot in your mouth . . .